# Pseudo-random numbers from a 32-bit auto-increment INTEGER

Tags: math, random

I have a table with an auto-increment 32-bit integer primary key in a database, which will produce numbers ranging `1-4294967295`.

I would like to keep the convenience of an auto-generated primary key, while having my numbers on the front-end of an application look like randomly generated.

Is there a mathematical function which would allow a two-way, **one-to-one** transformation between an integer and another?

For example a function would take a number, and translate it to another:

```
1 => 1538645623
2 => 2043145593
3 =>  393439399
```

And another function the way back:

```
1538645623 => 1
2043145593 => 2
 393439399 => 3
```

I'm not necessarily looking for an implementation here, but rather a hint on what I suppose, must be a well-known mathematical problem somewhere :)

Comment: @Tomalak: To avoid people trying to guess what the next number will be. Not as good as a random one, but currently considering several possibilities!

Comment: @Benjamin: Why do you want to avoid people guessing what the next number will be? Obfuscation is largely a wasted effort.

Comment: If you really want to go down this route then you could just multiply by a big number.  That solves the problem (without the random element but who would know).  I havent put this as an answer because I think it's a crappy solution.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear in the question, but the number has to stay in the same 32-bit range. Also, given two consecutive numbers, a multiplication would make it too easy to guess how the stuff works!

Comment: @Tomalak, it's not a wasted effort. This is to protect a system against people trying to cheat it. Each number will be manually checked face to face, so there won't be many cheat attempts, except if the number sequence is obvious to the user.

Comment: @Benjamin: It won't take long for someone to figure out the pattern. Obfuscation _in general_ is largely a wasted effort. That's why they say to avoid "security by obfuscation", and instead make it so that if a user tries to "cheat" your system (whatever that means here), it _doesn't matter_.

Comment: @Tomalak, I don't understand your point. First, the solution suggested by Nick below is very good. Using a cryptographic function to "encode" the number, nobody will be able to "figure out the pattern" unless either they know what the key is, or they have a large enough number of numbers to build an attack. None of these scenarios is really plausible, as the benefit is not worth the trouble. However, it does always matter if a user tries to cheat the system: consider this number as a coupon, if someone is able to guess what the next coupon number will be, then someone else will be  stolen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematically this is almost exactly the same problem as cryptography.

You: I want to go from an id(string of bits) to another number (string of bits) and back again in a non-obvious way.
Cryptography: I want to go from plaintext (string of bits) to another string of bits and back again (reversible) in a non-obvious way.

So for a simple solution, can I suggest just plugging in whatever cryptography algorithm is most convenient in your language, and encrypt and decrypt your id?

If you wanted to be a bit cleverer you can do what is called "salting" in addition to cryptography. Take your id as a 32 bit (or whatever) number. Concatenate it with a random 32 bit number. Encrypt the result. To reverse, just decrypt, and throw away the random part.

Of course, if someone was seriously attacking this, this might be vulnerable to known plaintext/differential cryptanalysis attacks as you have a very small known plaintext space, but it sounds like you aren't trying to defend against serious attacks.

Comment: Very constructive answer, thanks. Indeed, it is very similar to cryptography!

Comment: This is one of the many applications of cryptography, it's not just about transmitting secret messages.

Answer (score 2):

First remove the offset of 1, so you get numbers in the range 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-2. Let m = 2<sup>32</sup>-1.

Choose some `a` that is relative prime to `m`. Since it is relatively prime it has an inverse a' so that `a * a' = 1 (mod m)`. Also choose some `b`. Choose big numbers to get a good mixing effect.

Then you can compute your desired pseudo-random number by `y = (a * x + b) % m`, and get back the original by `x = ((y - b) * a') % m`.

This is essentially one step of a linear congruential generator (LCG) for pseudo-random numbers.

Note that this is not secure, it is only obfuscation. For example, if a user can get two numbers in sequence then he can recover `a` and `b` easily.

Comment: Woah, I'm impressed! Exactly the kind of answer I was waiting for. Maybe a bit complicated to implement, but it's really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases web apps use a hash of a randomly generated number as a reference to a table row. This hash can be stored as a number and displayed as a string for the end user.

This hash is unique and it is identifier and the id is only used in the application itself, never shown to the outside world.

Comment: The problem is that a hash is *one-way* only (you cannot get the number back from the hash), and in my case the number has to stay short (will be hand typed), so we cannot rely on the fact that a (MD5, for example) hash is not likely to have a collision. There is no *one-to-one* correlation.